# Neo4J - Linked List: returning results without order

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j server and I have to resolve this use case:

I have a linked list of comments and I want to get the most recent comments with their author and the name of the author who like them, so my linked list is the following one:

```
(Resource)-[:COMMENTS]->(Comment)-[:NEXT]->(Comment)-...-[:NEXT]->(Comment)

(User)-[:LIKES]->(Comment)

(User)-[:MAKES]->(Comment)
```

I want Neo4j to retrieve for every Comment:

```
{text: comment_text,
 date: comment_date,
 author: comment_author,
 likes: [users_who_like_the_comment] }
```

I made this query:

```
MATCH (r)-[:COMMENTS|NEXT*0..3]->(cc:Comment)<-[:LIKES]-(a:User)
WHERE id(r)=6468
WITH r,a, collect(cc) AS Likes
MATCH r-[:COMMENTS|NEXT*0..3]->(c:Comment), (u:User)-[:MAKES]->c
WITH Likes,c,u,a
RETURN {text: c.text, date: c.date, author: u.name, likes: CASE WHEN (c) in Likes THEN collect(a.name) END } as Comments
```

The problem is that I get the correct result but without order, which should be provided by default in a linked list, so I guess I'm doing something wrong but I'm not able to figure out what...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
MATCH (r)-[:COMMENTS]->()-[NEXT*0..3]->(c:Comment)<-[:MAKES]-(u:User)
WHERE id(r)=6468
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:LIKES]-(a:User)
RETURN {text: c.text, date: c.date, author: u.name, likes: collect(a.name)} as Comments
```

if that doesn't keep the order, you can change it to:

```
MATCH path=(r)-[:COMMENTS]->()-[*NEXT*0..3]->(c:Comment)<-[:MAKES]-(u:User)
WHERE id(r)=6468
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:LIKES]-(a:User)
WITH {text: c.text, date: c.date, author: u.name, likes: collect(a.name)} as Comments, 
     length(path) as len
ORDER BY len ASC
RETURN Comments
```

And for good measure here is everything as a [GraphGist](http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?800d0d4b4f83467ffdd5)

Comment: @carlosytal If the provided answer work for you, remember to accept it!